# Antialiasing and gamma compensation

Tags: graphics, antialiasing, gamma

The luminence of pixels on a computer screen is not usually linearly related to the digital RGB triplet values of a pixel.  The nonlinear response of early CRTs required a compensating nonlinear encoding and we continue to use such encodings today.

Usually we produce images on a computer screen and consume them there as well, so it all works fine.  But when we antialias, the nonlinearity — called gamma — means that we can't just add an alpha value of 0.5 to a 50% covered pixel and expect it to look right.  An alpha value of 0.5 is only 0.5^2.2=22% as bright as an alpha of 1.0 with a typical gamma of 2.2.

Is there any widely established best practice for antialiasing gamma compensation?  Do you have a pet method you use from day to day?  Has anyone seen any studies of the results and human perceptions of the quality of the graphic output with different techniques?

I've thought of doing standard X^(1/2.2) compensation but that is pretty computationally intense.  Maybe I can make it faster with a 256 entry lookup table, though.

Answer (score 2):

Lookup tables are used quite often for work like that.  They're small and fast.

But whether look-up or some formula, if the end result is an image file, and the format permits, it's best to save a color profile or at least the gamma value in the file for later viewing, rather than try adjusting RGB values yourself.

The reason:  for typical byte-valued R, G, B channels, you have 256 unique values in each channel at each pixel. That's almost good enough to look good to the human eye (I wish "byte" had been defined as nine bits!)  Any kind of math, aside from trivial value inversion, would map many-to-one for some of those values.  The output won't have 256 values to pick from for each pixel for R, G, or B, but far fewer. That can lead to contouring, jaggies, color noise  and other badness.

Precision issues aside, if any kind of decent quality is desired, all composting, mixing, blending, color correction, fake lens flare addition, chroma-keying and whatever, should be done in linear RGB space, where the values of R, G and B are in proportion to physical light intensity.  The image math mimics physical light math.  But where ultimate speed is vital, there are ways to cheat.

Comment: Nine bit bytes? Do you like octal that much? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Jim Blinns - "Dirty Pixels" book outlines a fast and good compositing calculation by using 16 bit math plus lookup tables to accurately go back and forward to linear color space. This guy worked on NASAs visualisations, he *knows* his stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to answer, though mainly for reference now, to the actual questions:

First, there are the recommendations from ITU (http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.272-200701-I/en) which can be applied to programming (but you have to know your stuff).

In Jim Blinn's "Notation, Notation, Notation", Chapter 9, has a very detailed mathematical and perceptual error analysis, although he only covers compositing (many other graphics tasks are affected too).

The notation he establishes can also be used to derive a way of dealing with gamma, or to check if a given way of doing so is actually correct. Very handy, my pet method (mainly as I discovered it independently but later found his book).

Answer (score 1):

When generating images, one typically works in a linear color space (like linear RGB or one of the CIE color spaces) and then converts to a non-linear RGB space at the end.  That conversion can be accelerated in hardware or via lookup tables or even through tricky math.  (See the other answers' references.)

When performing an alpha blend (e.g., render this icon onto this background), this kind of precision is often elided in favor of speed.  The results are computed directly in the non-linear RGB-space by lerping with the alpha as the parameter.  This is not "correct", but it's good enough in most cases.  Especially for things like icons on desktops.

If you're trying to do more correct blending, you treat it like an original render.  Work in linear space (which may require an initial conversion) and then convert to your non-linear display space at the end.

A lot of graphics nowadays use sRGB as the non-linear display color space.  If I recall correctly, sRGB is very similar to a gamma of 2.2, but there are adjustments made to values at the low end.